# How can I make my code read the entire file?

Tags: python-3.6

I can't make my code read the entire file even though I've used readlines() already.

```
global i
i = 1
def main( go ):
    print("Enter barcode")
    f = open("test.txt","r")
    bar = input()
    global i
    while i == 1:
        first = f.readlines()
        if bar in first:
            print(first)
            print("y")
            main("go")
        else:
            print("no")
            main("go")
main("go")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'readlines()', you get an array with all the lines of the file and you can use. Try this:

```
first=f.readlines()
for line in first:
    print (line)
```

and you will get all lines printed.
This is your code fixed:

```
global i
i = 1
def main( go ):
    print("Enter barcode")
    f = open("test.txt","r")
    bar = input()
    global i
    first = f.readlines()
    for line in first:
        if bar in line:
            print(line)
            print("y")
        else:
            print("no")
main("go")
```